# middleware not working when passing parameters

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, handler

Middleware File -

```
const access_validation_middleware  = async function(action:any, resource:any){
   console.log("came inside")
   return async (req:any, res:any, next:any) => {
      console.log("came inside async")
      try {
         //   const permission = roles.can(req.user.role)[action](resource);
           // Do something
           next();
       }
       catch (error) {
           next(error)
       }
   }
}
export default access_validation_middleware;
```

Controller -

```
const usersRouter = Router();
usersRouter.get('/',access_validation_middleware, UserController.list)
export default usersRouter
```

When I am using this middleware, API keeps loading. it doesn't even reaches till the anonymous function in access_validation_middleware.
When I remove the middleware, it is giveing response well.

Comment: Remove `async` for `access_validation_middleware`, then, use it like `usersRouter.get('/',access_validation_middleware('create', 'tag'), UserController.list)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add another middleware that puts action and resource on req like this

```
export const putPayload = async(req,res,next)=>{ if(validateRequest(req)){ req.action = whateverAction; req.resource = whateverResource; next();} else {res.status(400).json({message:"bad request!"});}}
```

and before this define a validation function like this anywhere:

```
export const validateRequest(req)=>{if(DO_YOUR_VALIDATION) return true; return false;}
```

then change your middleware access_validation_middleware to :

```
export const access_validation_middleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("came inside async")
  try {
     //   const permission = roles.can(req.user.role)[req.action](req.resource);
       // Do something
       next();
   }
   catch (error) {
       next(error)
   }
}
```

then in your router do like this:

```
const router = express.Router();
router.route("/").get(putPayload , access_validation_middleware , UserController.list)
```

I hope it helps